# My device supports the ARCore Depth API, yet the Hello AR sample app shows an error

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, huawei-mobile-services

I have an Honor v20 and it supports ARCore Depth API. I'm able to run all sorts of AR apps that require Depth and TOF sensor just fine (such as "ARuler", "Depth Labs" and "Lines of Play"). However, when I compile and run Google's HelloAR sample app, I get the following message on the screen of the Honor v20:

> Your device doesn't support depth.

Has anybody experienced this issue? How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Unity make sure that **ARCore Supported** option is **enabled** from  ***File > Build Settings > Player Settings > XR Settings***.

Comment: Yes, I did already enable that setting. App still doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the ARCore Device and check the AR Session Config there and see if the Depth Mode is Disabled or Automatic if it is automatic select Disabled
**Assets > GoogleARCore > Examples > HelloAR > HelloARSessionConfig**